# Reinstalling any OS on Ideapad 100S

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bios

I've been given a Lenovo Ideapad 100S-11IBY.

It doesn't boot and the drive is empty, completely blank, not even a recovery partition.

I've tried making Windows 7 and Windows 10 USB boot disks but they don't show in the boot manager, and I've disabled/enabled secure boot in the bios to rule that out too. The bios is very limited.

There must be a way to boot from a Windows disk to reinstall the OS

[image: Lenovo Ideapad 100S]

Comment: Windows 7 is not supported. Prepare a Windows 10 **USB stick** preferably using the Windows official tool, in another Windows PC. And have the drivers ready, it needs a few even with Windows 10.

Comment: I've used the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool to make a bootable USB but it doesn't appear in the boot manager.

Comment: What boot manager? You need to open UEFI settings and change the boot order there.

Comment: I think Lenovo is notorious for locking other OSes out through their BIOS/UEFI. Also see [Lenovo slammed for OS-locking BIOS block](https://www.bit-tech.net/news/tech/laptops/lenovo-os-blocking-bios-lock/1/).

Answer (score -1):

If there's no optical drive, then you can install Windows from a flash drive, no problem. To do this, grab a flash drive (At least 8GB), stick it into another computer, then Download Windows 10 [from this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Use the Microsoft utility to create the bootable Windows 10 flash drive. Now you can install Windows 10 by booting from this flash drive.

Comment: Why not download it from Microsoft directly instead of "some website"? And why not the official Microsoft tool right away (same download), why a third-party tool? And no, it doesn't need to be *at least 32GB*. Microsoft asks for 8GB because the ISO is ~4.6GB.